# Magento Won't Accept New Fedex Number

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I'm sure that Title sounds cryptic . ..

As you probably know, in order to get Magento to integrate with Fedex so that it will print shipping labels, you have to setup a test account with Fedex, jump through some hoops, and then they approve you for it.

Well, I got a test account number and set it up in Magento, but it's not working.  I finally checked the logs and .... low and behold the Account ID that it is sending to Fedex is my REAL account number (even though it is using all the other test credentials. . .meter number password etc).

In short . . . Magento is accepting all the account changes EXCEPT the actual account number.   Fedex has confirmed they are seeing the info via my REAL account info trying to get to the Fedex server.

This must be some sort of Magento glitch, does anyone have a workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have maybe it set to not use default settings at the website or store level. I suggest you check this - the scope dropdown is on top right hand side.

Its only going to use your real number if you have inputted it somewhere. So its either not saving (which you would be notified of) or its a scope issue.

If all else fails go look direct in core_config_data.

Also bear in mind that in the admin panel the default configuration scope is used, so if you do just have set at a website level but not at the default level that will be your issue.